# Accounting for camera smear/motion blur in distance calculation

Tags: opencv, image-processing, computer-vision

I'm working on a tracker, which calculates the distance of a blob by the amount of pixels. All is going well whenever the camera is still and I get pretty accurate readings. However as the camera moves, the blob seems bigger and thus it seems closer by to the processor.

I was thinking that I could use the amount of movement measured by the gyroscope and accelerometers to account for the smear with a formula, as the biggest problem is in smear by rotation.

Given my measurement of movement is 0..1 (0 being no movement, 1 being 90 degrees turn), how could I account for the smear reasonably accurate?

Comment: Please note that smear is also the name of a different phenomenon within cameras! You are obviously talking about motion blur. These terms are more common in image-processing, although I also know smear as a term in optics, which is basically the same as motion blur.

Comment: Thanks Piglet, I changed the title to accomodate that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With some assumptions on the movement model of the object you're tracking, this sounds like it could be solved by fusing the pixels number and gyro sources of information using a Kalman filter.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kalman_filter

In laymen terms, the filter would use the gyro information as an indicator of how much to trust the number of pixels.  When movement is high, it would tend to use previous information, with the assumption that the object couldn't have moved much in one frame.

Comment: I used a lowpassfilter just now, with the alpha influenced by movement. I figure it's not far off from your idea using a Kalman filter (but easier to implement for me). It works pretty well from the looks of it, thanks!